# Cache Headers When Deploying A Static Site To Zeit Now

Tags: caching, vercel

I am deploying a static site built with Gatsby to [Zeit Now](https://zeit.co/now). I need to set the cache headers for all JavaScript and Image resources to:

```
cache-control: public,max-age=31536000,immutable
```

However Now doesn't appear to support any [configuration](https://zeit.co/docs/features/configuration) options and doesn't cover setting cache-control headers anywhere in its documentation.

**How can I change the headers it uses for JavaScript and Image files?**

Answer (score 0):

Since you site is static, you'll want to make sure you using the [static build type](https://zeit.co/docs/deployment-types/static) in your `now.json` file like so:

```
{
  "type": "static",
  "static": {
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)",
        "headers": [{
          "key": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "max-age=7200"
        }]
      }, {
        "source": "404.html",
        "headers": [{
          "key": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "public,max-age=31536000,immutable"
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this only applies to Zeit v1, v2 does not support either the type or static property

Comment: Correct! This question was asked before v2 was released so it only pertains to v1. The docs show correct usage for v2 here: https://zeit.co/docs/v2/advanced/configuration#routes